# What is the difference between clock_gettime() and timespec_get()?

Tags: c, time, clock

I tried `clock_gettime()` and `timespec_get()` but what is the difference?

Can anyone help me to find the difference between `clock_gettime()` and `timespec_get()`?

Comment: Reading some [`clock_gettime`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_gettime.html) and [`timespec_get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/timespec_get) documentation, it seems they only differ in what specification includes them. `clock_gettime` is POSIX while `timespec_get` is standard C.

Answer (score 0):

`clock_gettime(clockid_t, struct timespec *)` (declared in `time.h`) can return different time values based on `clockid_t`. You should read the man page.

`timespec_get(struct timespec *, int)` (also declared in `time.h`) sets the object value to time since the Epoch (1.1.1970, midnight).

*This should be ideally same as calling `clock_gettime()` with `clockid_t` as `CLOCK_REALTIME`.*

The second argument here is base or time-zone. So using `TIME_UTC` would give the GMT.

Not all C compilers support this on every platforms.
Edit after comments:

1. `timespec_get()` is standardised in ISO **C11** standards.
2. `clock_gettime()`, however is standardised by POSIX standards and on systems where this is available, the symbol `_POSIX_TIMERS` is set to a non-zero value (in `unistd.h`).

Comment: that's not true. `timespec_get` is standard C11

Comment: C11 defines [`timespec_get()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.27.2.5) and POSIX defines [`clock_gettime()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_gettime.html).  Both functions are standard — but they are standardized by different standards.